# Unable to trigger java class from lambda AWS

Tags: spring, maven, aws-lambda, java-7

I just want to trigger a sample java program through lambda.
So I made two classes in com.amazonaws.lambda package of /src/main /java that is LambdaFunctionHandler.java and MessageService.java.

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
@Component
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<Object, String> 
{

@Autowired
private MessageService messsageService;

public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {

    return messsageService.getMessage();
}
}
```

And 2nd class is

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda;

  public class MessageService {

public String getMessage() {
    return "hello world";
}
}
```

I am uploading jar file on S3 bucket and triggering it from lambda then getting below error :

```
{
    "errorMessage": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "errorType": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "stackTrace": 
    [
        "com.amazonaws.lambda.autorfexecution.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:16)",
        "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
        "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
        "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
        "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
    ]
}
```

TextContext.java

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda;

 import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.ClientContext;
 import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.CognitoIdentity;
 import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
 import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;

  public class TestContext implements Context {

private String awsRequestId = "EXAMPLE";
private ClientContext clientContext;
private String functionName = "EXAMPLE";
private CognitoIdentity identity;
private String logGroupName = "EXAMPLE";
private String logStreamName = "EXAMPLE";
private LambdaLogger logger = new TestLogger();
private int memoryLimitInMB = 128;
private int remainingTimeInMillis = 15000;
private String functionVersion = "EXAMPLE";
private String invokedFunctionArn = "EXAMPLE";

@Override
public String getAwsRequestId() {
    return awsRequestId;
}

public void setAwsRequestId(String value) {
    awsRequestId = value;
}

@Override
public ClientContext getClientContext() {
    return clientContext;
}

public void setClientContext(ClientContext value) {
    clientContext = value;
}

@Override
public String getFunctionName() {
    return functionName;
}

public void setFunctionName(String value) {
    functionName = value;
}

@Override
public CognitoIdentity getIdentity() {
    return identity;
}

public void setIdentity(CognitoIdentity value) {
    identity = value;
}

@Override
public String getLogGroupName() {
    return logGroupName;
}

public void setLogGroupName(String value) {
    logGroupName = value;
}

@Override
public String getLogStreamName() {
    return logStreamName;
}

public void setLogStreamName(String value) {
    logStreamName = value;
}

@Override
public LambdaLogger getLogger() {
    return logger;
}

public void setLogger(LambdaLogger value) {
    logger = value;
}

@Override
public int getMemoryLimitInMB() {
    return memoryLimitInMB;
}

public void setMemoryLimitInMB(int value) {
    memoryLimitInMB = value;
}

@Override
public int getRemainingTimeInMillis() {
    return remainingTimeInMillis;
}

public void setRemainingTimeInMillis(int value) {
    remainingTimeInMillis = value;
}

@Override
public String getFunctionVersion() {
    return functionVersion;
}

public void setFunctionVersion(String value) {
    functionVersion = value;
}

@Override
public String getInvokedFunctionArn() {
    return invokedFunctionArn;
}

public void setInvokedFunctionArn(String value) {
    invokedFunctionArn = value;
}

/**
 * A simple {@code LambdaLogger} that prints everything to stderr.
 */
private static class TestLogger implements LambdaLogger {

    @Override
    public void log(String message) {
        System.err.println(message);
    }
}
}
```

So anyone please guide me what is missing here.

Comment: You are missing **everything** spring related. Do you anywhere start initializing the application context? See e.g. https://www.ccampo.me/java/spring/aws/2016/11/27/spring-aws-lambda.html

Comment: is it necessary to use application context as when I am using simply one class that is LambdaFunctionHandler and print anything then if i am triggering it then it is working fine.

Comment: Without a spring context nothing gets autowired, period.

Comment: And I am using text context.Also I have attached it.
I am able to do autowiring